# Is there a way to delete a .dll file without using separate app domains?

Tags: c#, assemblies, appdomain, codedom

I am using CodeDOM to dynamically generate classes. I am specifying the output assembly so a .dll is created with the class name. These classes will need to be updated with the same class name, however, so the class will be updated whereas the .dll will not be updated (since it can't overwrite the previous .dll). I'm wondering if there is a way to call a method that will delete this .dll and then when I generate the new class the new .dll will appear there. I know I could use app domains, but the problem is I need to update classes frequently and I think performance will suffer a lot.

Comment: Use Roslyn instead, so you can compile in-memory.

Comment: If you need to do frequent updates, why are you saving the DLL to the disk in the first place? .NET is happy to have a memory-only assembly for cases just like this.

Comment: The cost of an appdomain should be insignificant compare to the cost of generating code, compiling it, and writing the DLL to disk.

Comment: Oh I wasn't even aware of compiling in-memory. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can delete/recreate the DLL if and only if that DLL file is not currently open.  It is open if one or more app domains is have the DLL code loaded into the domain.

There is no facility to unload a DLL from an app domain.  You must unload the app domain to unload any DLLs it references.

*UPDATE*

I was not aware of Roslyn's ability to compile in-memory per @SLaks suggestion.  If you are not tied to a physical DLL, have a look at [this article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn).